# Aligning a text and line parallel

Tags: html, css

[image]

There are 4 div's which has text and a line. The text will be coming from the service call and it may vary. The issue is that the line is not properly displayed it is of different length.The main condition is 
1)All the line should end at the same point.
2)The line should be of 30px right from the margin and 
3)The gap between the text and line should be 12px.

```css
.about{
    display: inline-block;
}
hr{
  display:inline-block;
  width:200px;
}
```

```html
<div>

<div class="about">Chapter</div><hr/></div>
<div>
<div class="about">Learning Objectives</div><hr/></div>
<div>
<div class="about">Pages</div><hr/></div>
<div>
<div class="about">Sections</div><hr/></div>
```

I tried with min,max-width but unable find a solution.Can anyone give a better solution?

Comment: What you want to do..? Can you provide any screenshot..?

Comment: all you did here is specify a min of 200px.

Comment: @Hema Nandagopal check my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```css
.about {
  float: left;  
}
hr {
  width: auto;
  margin-left: 30px;
}
.test {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">
  <div class="about">Chapter</div>
  <hr/>
</div>
<div class="test">
  <div class="about">Learning Objectives</div>
  <hr/>
</div>
<div class="test">
  <div class="about">Pages</div>
  <hr/>
</div>
<div class="test">
  <div class="about">hhhhhhhhhhhhhhh</div>
  <hr/>
</div>
```

Comment: Here is the actual issue, the padding between the line and text should be 12px irrespective of the text length

Comment: That's really great.Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Make some changes to your CSS as:

```
.about {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin-right: 12px;
}
hr{
  display:inline-block;
  width:200px;
  margin-bottom:0;
}
```

```css
.about {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right:12px;
  vertical-align: top;
}
hr{
  display:inline-block;
  width:200px;
  margin-bottom:0;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="about">Chapter</div><hr/>
</div>
<div>
  <div class="about">Learning Objectives</div><hr/>
</div>  
<div>
  <div class="about">Pages</div><hr/>
</div>  
<div>
  <div class="about">hhhhhhhhhhhhhhh</div><hr/>
</div>
```

Comment: Here is the actual issue, the padding between the line and text should be 12px irrespective of the text length.

Comment: check now change some css

Comment: What you have and  I did was same but the line should end same for all the div's.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.about{
  display: inline-block;
}
hr{
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 3px;
}
```

```html
<div>

<div class="about">Chapter</div><hr/></div>
<div>
<div class="about">Learning Objectives</div><hr/></div>
<div>
<div class="about">Pages</div><hr/></div>
<div>
<div class="about">hhhhhhhhhhhhhhh</div><hr/></div>
```

Comment: Updated the question.All the line should have same end from right.

Answer (score 0):

You can get this simply with `display:flex;` to parent.

Try this solution.

```css
.align{
   display:flex;
}

.about{
   padding-right:12px;

}
hr{
  width:200px;
     margin-left: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="align">

<div class="about">Chapter</div><hr /></div>
<div class="align">
<div class="about">Learning Objectives</div><hr/></div>
<div class="align">
<div class="about">Pages</div><hr/></div>
<div class="align">
<div class="about">hhhhhhhhhhhhhhh</div><hr/></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way..

You can do it using `jquery` also. ( Since there is no `jquery` tag in your question, take this as a secondary choice.)

```
$("hr").each(function() {
  var abtwidth = $(this).parent().find(".about").width();
  var hrwidth = 300 - abtwidth;
  $(this).css('width',hrwidth);
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/wqe7v3d7/)

Comment: Yeah,but we don't use jquery in the project :( .BTW Thanks :)

Comment: ohk..no problem..  :)